# Meaning of lo: in R

Tags: r

I have this example of adding a new table attribute(IMCmod) that tells you if the variable IMD is lesser than 22 in one of the pdfs in my class:

```
TE<-data.frame(TE,IMCmod=recode(TE$IMC,"lo:22=1;else=0"))
```

So, my question is does the lo: mean ¨lesser than¨ and if it does, what's the codeword for ¨greater than¨

PD: I feel like it's a dumb question to ask here, but I haven't been able to find it anywhere, so please bear with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the `recode` function from the `car` package, `lo` stands for the lowest value of the variable, so `"lo:22=1;else=0"` means "all values from the lowest to 22 are recoded to 1; others are recoded to 0".

Note that `x:y` means the entire range from `x` to `y`, it's not the sequence operator as in R code, so 3.1415 would be included as long as the lowest value was smaller.

You can use `hi` for the highest value.

For more details, see `?recode`.